# Add a CALCULATED fields with if-else condition in Django model

Tags: django-models

How can i add a calculated field with if-else condition in Django model?
for instance,

```
def _get_total(self):
   "Returns the Overall Backlog"
   return self.Forecast - self.Actual_t
Overall_Backlog = property(_get_total)
```

here, i want to create `Overall_Backlog` with a condition like if `(self.Forecast - self.Actual_t)<0` then `0` else `(self.Forecast - self.Actual_t)`.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like that:

```
@property
def Overall_Backlog(self):
   "Returns the Overall Backlog"
    val = self.Forecast - self.Actual_t
    if val < 0:
        return 0
    return val
```

A disadvantage of using a property is however that the database does not know anything about properties and methods, and thus can not filter. An alternative to using properties is using [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    overall_backlog=Greatest(F('Forecast') - F('Actual_t'), Value(0))
)
```

The `MyModel` objects that arise from *this* `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.overall_backlog` that is the maximum of `Forecast - Actual_t` and `0`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying.. i did the second approach by adding this annotate thing in models.py file. and got an error that mymodel (here dem_tool in my case) is not defined.. i used this annotate function within dem_tool class only. Can you suggest how to get it running?    PS I'm a newbie with no such background, so, ignore my stupid questions .. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GauravNailwal: `MyModel` is the *model class*, so if the model name is `dem_tool`, it should be `dem_tool.objects.annotate(..)`

Comment: Did that but got an error that dem_tools is not defined.

Comment: @GauravNailwal: but you need to import it in the view where you use the queryset.

Comment: Hi Willem, you're right about Property, i'm not able to access this field via queryset method. But i'm not able to implement annotate method.. as mentioned, i'm a newbie in this, can you please help like where to add this exactly.